# Get the list of tr elements having the same data answer id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following data where I want to remove the row and it's associated child rows.

This is displayed in screen-shot

[image: screenshot]

With the following I am trying to delete all child rows whose `data-answer-id` is equal to the `data-question-id` of the `tr` because that is what defined as parent/child records.

I am trying something like this:

```
var table = $("table#sortable tbody");
var childrens =  $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-question-id'); 
var childrens =  $(thisRow).hasClass('parent').attr('data-question-id');
table.find('tr.childrow').each(function (key) {
    <!--- missing this piece here need to create a comma separated list -->
});
```

Comment: Go read up on how the _attribute selector_ works. This doesn’t need any loops and creation of comma separated lists, this can be done using the proper selector, and then simply calling `remove` once.

Comment: dont uset attr... use data

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's not quite clear about whether you want to delete all rows with "data-answer-id" attribute or just specific row which have specific "data-answer-id" value.
I'm assuming that below code returns the value of particular "data-question-id" which you want to delete.

```
$(this).closest('tr').attr('data-question-id')
```

So as per your snapshot this should return 130. Then you can delete all  which have data-answer-id=130 by following attribute selector.

```
$('[data-answer-id=130]').remove();
```

Your complete code would be like below.

```
var table = $("table#sortable tbody");
var questionid =  $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-question-id'); 
table.find('tr.childrow[data-answer-id=' + questionid + ']').remove();
```